# Populating select list

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 3 columns in a table in db: ID, TITLE, TEXT and that will populate form select options.
Depending on user selection, script will take title and text and with some changes put all that into a different table.

The question I'm asking is, how efficient is to populate select option like this?

```
<option value="TEXT"> TITLE </option>
```

This seems like the most easiest way but text can be quite long (more that 500 characters), and there will be like 10 titles to choose from.

Second thing I'm thinking is to do it like this

```
<option value="ID"> TITLE </option>
```

and then when user selects, script will need to again call database to fetch row with corresponding ID.

What is better and efficient with less code? Is there something else that could be done?

Comment: Why not just store the ID in the database (as a FK) and join when fetching the results?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think (IMHO) that the "id" solution is the better EVER!
This because what the user need to see it's different on how you manage this, you think with id, the user think with "description" so, you need the id and the user need the "title".

The best and more efficient is this one for me.